# Julia PlotlyJS delay show plot, update plot

Tags: electron, julia, plotly, blink

I'm trying to include a plot using the PlotlyJS package in a small application using Blink.
So far, whenever I use the plot function, it opens a new window, which I want to avoid..
Furthermore, when updating the plot, another window pops up - also not wanted.
Does anyone know how to avoid these new windows? Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
using PlotlyJS,Blink

scatter_1 = scatter(;x=rand(10),y=rand(10))
p = plot(scatter_1) # first unwanted window

w = Window()
body!(w,p)

scatter_2 = scatter(;x = 2*rand(10), y = 2*rand(10))
addtraces(p, scatter_2) #second unwated window
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `;` at the end of the line.

```
using PlotlyJS,Blink

scatter_1 = scatter(;x=rand(10),y=rand(10))
p = plot(scatter_1);

w = Window()
body!(w,p)

scatter_2 = scatter(;x = 2*rand(10), y = 2*rand(10))
addtraces(p, scatter_2);
```

Comment: It was that simple... hard to believe; Thanks!